# Does collect_list() maintain relative ordering of rows?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Imagine that I have the following DataFrame df:

```
+---+-----------+------------+
| id|featureName|featureValue|
+---+-----------+------------+
|id1|          a|           3|
|id1|          b|           4|
|id2|          a|           2|
|id2|          c|           5|
|id3|          d|           9|
+---+-----------+------------+
```

Imagine that I run:

```
df.groupBy("id")
  .agg(collect_list($"featureIndex").as("idx"),
       collect_list($"featureValue").as("val"))
```

Am I **GUARANTEED** that "idx" and "val" will be aggregated and keep their relative order? i.e.

```
GOOD                   GOOD                   BAD
+---+------+------+    +---+------+------+    +---+------+------+
| id|   idx|   val|    | id|   idx|   val|    | id|   idx|   val|
+---+------+------+    +---+------+------+    +---+------+------+
|id3|   [d]|   [9]|    |id3|   [d]|   [9]|    |id3|   [d]|   [9]|
|id1|[a, b]|[3, 4]|    |id1|[b, a]|[4, 3]|    |id1|[a, b]|[4, 3]|
|id2|[a, c]|[2, 5]|    |id2|[c, a]|[5, 2]|    |id2|[a, c]|[5, 2]|
+---+------+------+    +---+------+------+    +---+------+------+
```

NOTE: e.g. It's BAD because for id1 [a, b] should have been associated with [3, 4] (and not [4, 3]). Same for id2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you can rely on *"their relative order"* as Spark goes over rows one by one in order (and *usually* does not re-order rows if not explicitly needed).

If you are concerned with the order, merge these two columns using [struct](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@struct(colName:String,colNames:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function before doing `groupBy`.

> **struct(colName: String, colNames: String*): Column** Creates a new struct column that composes multiple input columns.

You could also use [monotonically_increasing_id](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@monotonically_increasing_id():org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function to number records and use it to pair with the other columns (perhaps using `struct`):

> **monotonically_increasing_id(): Column** A column expression that generates monotonically increasing 64-bit integers.
>
> The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and unique, but not consecutive.

Comment: So Spark DataFrame distribute the processing of the data 'horizontally' rather than 'vertically'. i.e. One executor will always receive the entire row and not only a few columns of it?

Comment: Yes. Row is always in its entirety on one single executor/node.