# Combine multiple rows into a single row

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to achieve this via pyspark building sql.
The goal is to combine multiple rows into single row
Example:
I want to convert this

```
+-----+----+----+-----+
| col1|col2|col3| col4|
+-----+----+----+-----+
|x    |  y |  z |13::1|
|x    |  y |  z |10::2|
+-----+----+----+-----+
```

To

```
+-----+----+----+-----------+
| col1|col2|col3|       col4|
+-----+----+----+-----------+
|x    |  y |  z |13::1;10::2|
+-----+----+----+-----------+
```

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're looking for is the spark-sql version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41789093/5858851), which is the following:

```python
query = """
  select col1, 
         col2, 
         col3, 
         concat_ws(';', collect_list(col4)) as col4 
    from some_table 
group by col1, 
         col2, 
         col3
"""
spark.sql(query).show()
#+----+----+----+-----------+
#|col1|col2|col3|       col4|
#+----+----+----+-----------+
#|   x|   y|   z|13::1;10::2|
#+----+----+----+-----------+
```

But be aware that since spark is distributed, this is not guaranteed to maintain any specific order, unless you explicitly specify the order.

See more:

- [collect_list by preserving order based on another variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50668635/5858851)
- [Does collect_list() maintain relative ordering of rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448008/does-collect-list-maintain-relative-ordering-of-rows)
- [Spark DataFrame: does groupBy after orderBy maintain that order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505599/spark-dataframe-does-groupby-after-orderby-maintain-that-order)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding upon the suggestion made by @Barmar in a comment, you can run a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, GROUP_CONCAT(col4)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Ike but I get the following exception
Undefined function: 'GROUP_CONCAT'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT() is a MySQL function. What database are you using?